# Rails: page-specific CSS class in a common layout

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, erb

How do I assign page-specific CSS classes to the tags that are used in common layout?

I have an **application.html.erb** layout file, which loads **application.css.scss** `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application". . . %>`, which, in its turn, uses all CSS files in directory (there's one **custom.css.scss** in my case).

I have four static pages and one layout. I want the Home page to be slightly different from the others: add a class to body for full-page background, make navigation of different colors, etc.

So what's my **application.html.erb** layout is looks like:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <head>
    ·
    ·
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      ·
      ·
    </header>
    ·
    <%= yield %>
    ·
  </body>
</html>
```

And my **home.html.erb**:

```
<div>
  Content unique for this page
</div>
```

So I want to assign some classes to the `<body>` and  `<header>` tags, but **only on the Home page**.

What's the best way to do this?

(I was thinking of creating an individual layout for Home page (and then an individual CSS for Home page, etc.. But I believe there's got to be another, better way).

Comment: Your `home page`, to which controller and action it belongs?

Comment: Check `#{params[:controller]}` and accordingly add class to body

Comment: @Vucko, it belongs to `StaticPagesController` and `home` action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `content_for` will be good for this.

In your layout **application.html.erb**:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <head>
    ·
    ·
  </head>
  <body class="<%= content_for :body_class %>">
    <header class="<%= content_for :header_class %>">
      ·
      ·
    </header>
    ·
    <%= yield %>
    ·
  </body>
</html>
```

In view **home.html.erb**:

```
<% content_for :body_class, 'class1' %>
<% content_for :header_class, 'class2' %>

<div>
  Content unique for this page
</div>
```

Its much more flexible and easier than use conditionals and check current controller with action.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

Comment: Love the simplicity of solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!